# Jenkins pipeline milestone not cancelling previous ongoing build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am experimenting with Jenkins pipeline and milestones and cannot figure out why Jenkins is not cancelling the previous build when a new build crosses the milestone.

Example Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    parameters {
        booleanParam(defaultValue: true, description: '', name: 'userFlag')
    }

    stages {
        stage("foo") {
            steps {
                milestone(ordinal: 1, label: "BUILD_START_MILESTONE")
                sh 'sleep 1000'
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Triggering this pipeline twice does not cancel the 1st job

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think the behavior is "If I'm a newer build that crosses this milestone, then all older build that crossed this milestone will be cancelled"

The actual behavior of the milestone step is that when a more recent pipeline crosses it first, then it prevents older pipeline from crossing that milestone.

Comment: Right -- the key is that the older builds that have already crossed the milestone are unaffected. The milestone forces builds to go through in sequential order but once they're through, it doesn't touch them.

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
/* This method should be added to your Jenkinsfile and called at the very beginning of the build*/
@NonCPS
def cancelPreviousBuilds() {
    def jobName = env.JOB_NAME
    def buildNumber = env.BUILD_NUMBER.toInteger()
    /* Get job name */
    def currentJob = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(jobName)

    /* Iterating over the builds for specific job */
    for (def build : currentJob.builds) {
        /* If there is a build that is currently running and it's not current build */
        if (build.isBuilding() && build.number.toInteger() != buildNumber) {
            /* Than stopping it */
            build.doStop()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting the following error with this solution in Groovy Sandbox -Scripts not permitted to use method hudson.model.Run getNumber. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.

Comment: @pasquers you need to allow it. Go to "Manage Jenkins" -> "In-process Scripts Approval" (https://yourJenkinsDomain/scriptApproval/)

Comment: @pasquers
I have added the following code as a workaround for Scripts not permitted error:

'''
//Added for scriptApproval
import hudson.model.Run
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods
import jenkins.model.CauseOfInterruption$UserInterruption
import hudson.model.Executor
'''

Answer (score 11):

I have a simple work around with [milestone plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-milestone-step), according to the [document](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-milestone-step/):

> - Builds pass milestones in order (taking the build number as sorter field).
> - Older builds will not proceed (they are aborted) if a newer one already passed the milestone.
> - When a build passes a milestone, any older build that passed the previous milestone but not this one is aborted.
> - Once a build passes the milestone, it will never be aborted by a newer build that didn't pass the milestone yet.

you can try something like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Stop Old Build') {
            steps {
                milestone label: '', ordinal:  Integer.parseInt(env.BUILD_ID) - 1
                milestone label: '', ordinal:  Integer.parseInt(env.BUILD_ID)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you can put this at the start of any pipeline.

Assume you just start a new build, #5. The first milestone, will be used to passes #4's second milestone, and the second milestone(of #5) will be used to kill #4's process, if it's currently running.

Comment: I dind't understand why this works.
According to the item `Once a build passes the milestone, it will never be aborted by a newer build that didn't pass the milestone yet.`, the build #4 shouldn't be stopped since it already passed the milestones, even if #5 passes it later. What am I missing?

Comment: Ok, now I think I got it.
It's because of `When a build passes a milestone, any older build that passed the previous milestone but not this one is aborted.`, right?

Comment: I found this doesn't work well if a previous build executed something inside `parallel`.

Comment: @kivagant - I have seen the same thing although I don't know how to setup and test it. For weeks the milestone method has been working well and just now I hit first instance where the previous build is not cancelling. My pipeline is using parallel stages across multiple nodes. I will try the other solution by sshepel and see if it is more predictable.

Answer (score 1):

The `disableConcurrentBuilds` property has been added to Pipeline.  The Pipeline syntax snippet generator offers the following syntax hint:

```
properties([disableConcurrentBuilds(abortPrevious: true)])
```

That property is used on ci.jenkins.io to cancel older plugin build jobs when newer plugin build jobs start.

Declarative Pipeline also includes the `disableConcurrentBuilds` option that is documented in the [Pipeline syntax page](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#available-options).

The declarative directive generator suggests the following:

```
options {
  disableConcurrentBuilds abortPrevious: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as per https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/10/16/stage-lock-milestone/, a pair of 'milestone()' works for me to kill the previous jobs while the pipeline kicked off for times,

```
stage('Build') {    
    // The first milestone step starts tracking concurrent build order
    milestone()
    node {
        echo "Building"
    }}

// The Deploy stage does not limit concurrency but requires manual input
// from a user. Several builds might reach this step waiting for input.
// When a user promotes a specific build all preceding builds are aborted,
// ensuring that the latest code is always deployed.
stage('Deploy') {
    timeout(time: 60, unit: 'SECONDS') {input "Deploy?"}    
    milestone()
    node {
        echo "Deploying"
    }
}
```

The last milestone helps kill previous builds if reached, say deploy button clicked for the above case. Or the locked resource released for the below case,

```
// This locked resource contains both Test stages as a single concurrency Unit.
// Only 1 concurrent build is allowed to utilize the test resources at a time.
// Newer builds are pulled off the queue first. When a build reaches the
// milestone at the end of the lock, all jobs started prior to the current
// build that are still waiting for the lock will be aborted
lock(resource: 'myResource', inversePrecedence: true){
  node('test') {
    stage('Unit Tests') {
      echo "Unit Tests"
    }
    stage('System Tests') {
      echo "System Tests"
    }
  }
  milestone()
}
```

Comment: what if you move the `milestone()` to right before `node` and after `lock`, what will be the behaviour? Just trying to understand. I understand what milestone is used for but what I don't understand is when it is used within `lock`. It's confusing me. Doesn't the lock allow only one thread (let's call it thread) to enter the block?

Answer (score 0):

Building on @D.W.'s answer, i found a simple pattern that works. It seems to fit into D.W.'s bullet #3 (which is the official doc): `When a build passes a milestone, Jenkins aborts older builds that passed the previous milestone but not this one.`

Adding an earlier milestone that everything will pass, and then one after the thing that is going to wait, makes it all work like you think it should. In my case:

```
steps {
  milestone 1
  input 'ok'
  milestone 2
}
```

Create two active builds with this, and only approve the second one. You'll see the first one get automatically canceled, because build 2 passed `milestone 2` first. 
Try taking out `milestone 1`, and you'll see that build 1 does *not* get canceled when build 2 passes `milestone 2`.

Adding the early milestone satisfies the requirement. It seems that a build has to pass *any* milestone before a future milestone passed by a newer build will cause it to cancel.